# HortonWorks “Table or view not found” when querying Hive from Excel using ODBC connection in Mac

Tags: excel, hadoop, hive, odbc, hortonworks-sandbox

I am using **Hortonworks sandbox 2.1** with **Apache Hive ODBC driver 2.1** and **iODBC**.

The `ODBC` connection is successful when I test it using the `iODBC` software. But, when I open excel and use Microsoft query to return the data to excel spreadsheet I get this error when I run SQL `SELECT` query

> : [Hortonworks][SQLEngine] (31740) Table or view not found:
>   HIVE.default.tweetsbi.

I am able to view the tables inside the database, but I can't view the content of them. Whenever I press Run I get the aforementioned error.

I am getting the same error in both `Excel 2011` and `2016`

[image]

Comment: Well, does `default.tweetsbi` table exist? Is that table in the default database?

Comment: Yes, I can access it from the browser. 
In Excel, I can see all the tables inside the database. But when I choose a table and I press run in Microsoft query to view the table content, this error appears.

Comment: Are you sure it's that error, or something like AccessDenied for your username?

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the error. I am able to connect successfully. But I can't view the content of the tables or return them to excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Hmm. Is the Hive keyword needed? I've not really used Excel / ODBC, but it's not needed with JDBC

Comment: This SQL statement is written by Microsoft query whenever I click on a table. I've deleted the Hive keyword but It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it to work by :

1. Editing the configuration of Hortonworks Hive ODBC Driver by
           changing UseNativeQuery from 0 to 1.
2. Give permission to the user "sandbox"

   ```
    hive
    grant SELECT on table tweetsbi to user sandbox;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Congrats, that you found a solution! However it may be that you don't want to grant sandbox access to your tables. I regard it as a bug in the Hortonworks driver, that this default HIVE databasename appears in the path.

Another - more general purpose - solution: Install the Microsoft Hive driver. Works fine and doesn't have the bug :-)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40886

ATB!

Croco